# Python Pandas: Concatenate pandas strings containing null

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate multiple string columns containing null values. But result does not show concatenated string rather just first column. How can I ignore values containing null? I tried to handle this by replacing nan values but that does not help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Addr1':['a','b','c'], 'Addr2':['', 'x', np.nan], 'Addr3':['202', '201', '203']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df1['patient address'] = df['Addr1'].astype(str).fillna('',) + " " 
+ df['Addr2'].astype(str).fillna('') + " " 
+ df['Addr3'].astype(str).fillna('') 
print(df1)
```

Expected output:

```
      patient address
0              a 202
1              b x 201
2              c 203
```

Comment: `.astype(str).fillna('')` --> `.fillna("").astype(str)`. I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, since it's such a small thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `groupby+agg` with `.join` on `level=0` , `stack()` by default drops the `NaN`:

```
df1['patient address'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

---

```
0     a  202
1    b x 201
2      c 203
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, I have other columns also in my bigger dataframe, which I don't want to concatenate. Can you please show how to add column names in your code

Comment: @PriyankaJ just select the columns you are interested in before `.stack..` , `df[['col1','col2'...]].stack()...`

Comment: stack and groupby has become one of my standard approach in almost all wrangling these days. so versatile.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Addr1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "Addr2": ["", "x", np.nan],
        "Addr3": ["202", "201", "203"],
    }
)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "patient address": df[["Addr1", "Addr2", "Addr3"]]
        .fillna(" ")
        .agg(" ".join, axis=1)
    }
)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  patient address
0          a  202
1         b x 201
2         c   203
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem. I see you have created the dataframe from dict, may be that cased the difference in output. Nevertheless, I don't want the nan in output . The stack method below works fine for me.

Comment: @PriyankaJ _I see you have created the dataframe from dict, may be that cased the difference in output._ It isn't. _Nevertheless, I don't want the nan in output _ Yes, I can't believe I missed that. I fixed that, if you want to take a look, I think it's slightly cleaner. Performance might be better, too.